# Electrolux refrigerator trips on Eaton 20 amp breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker, refrigerator

Refrigerator & house are 3 yrs old began tripping about 3 months ago.  Has tripped (4)times every 2 wks or so.  Eaton 20 amp breakers blinks 5 times indicating a "ground fault".  Breaker has been replaced, but to no avail. Fridge is separate from freezer.  Both are on separate breakers.  Also, I've had to replace 5 other Eaton breakers for tripping, seemingly for no reason.  Those replaced have not tripped again, except the fridge.

Comment: It very well might be a ground fault in the fridge. The timing suggests it could be the defrost heater or defrost timer.

Comment: Fridge or the circuit/wires have a ground fault.  Can test the fridge by using a heavy(12 gauge) extension cord plugged to another similar(20 amp GFCI breaker) circuit.  If the fridge trips again it is the fridge.

Comment: There may be a true ground fault or the breaker may be over-sensitive. Are there any other receptacles on the circuit? If so, are those receptacles in GFCI-required locations (e.g., kitchen countertop within 6' of sink)? Do you have any GFCI-receptacles (as opposed to GFCI-breakers)? If so, try plugging refrigerator into one of those.

Comment: It's the breaker's job to detect faults and shut off power before Something Bad™ happens, why does everyone assume that it's the breaker at fault and not that the breaker is doing its job and the appliance has a fault?

Comment: Where is the fridge located? Had a similar issue with a basement fridge that wasn't rated for that level of humidity.

Comment: Fridge is a separate unit from the freezer and on a separate breaker alone.  Located in the kitchen.  Thanks the comments.

Comment: If you had to replace 5 other ones there might be a good chance that the one you replaced for the fridge was bad too. More likely, and more importantly, you should check to confirm that something isn't shorting out.